# Is there any documentation for alert placeholder syntax with Logz.io / Kibana?

Tags: elastic-stack, logz.io

In Logz.io's ELK stack you have the ability to send alerts using a placeholder syntax such as

```
{{alert_event_samples}}
```

and

```
{{alert_title}}
```

I'm trying to track down any documentation that lists out all of these placeholders, because I'm in need of a placeholder that actually lists out **all** of the events, not just a sample.

I can't seem to find anything on this topic anywhere, other than some examples of how to integrate with other systems like slack.

Does anyone know where I can find anything on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is Josh from Logz.io support, we currently do not have the ability to sent all the events that triggered an alert to the alert endpoint as this could be many thousands of events.

All the current available placeholders that can be used in the alert endpoint are shown in the example JSON when creating a custom endpoint.  You can learn more about creating custom alert endpoints [here](http://support.logz.io/solution/articles/6000124027-how-do-i-integrate-the-logz-io-elk-stack-s-alerts-with-custom-messaging-platforms-).